# How to get source file name of global OBJECT/FUNC in an elf file?

Tags: c++, c, linux, elf

I have an ELF file, which I want to use to count the size of variables and functions in every C file.
For LOCAL types, I can distinguish them by files, for example:

```
   599: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS tcp.c
   600: 9b00cf14     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 $t
   601: 9b00cf15    84 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 tcp_new_port
   602: 9b00cf60     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 $d
   603: 9b00cf68     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 $t
   604: 9b00cf69    64 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 tcp_close_shutdown_fin
```

From the data above, we can know that there is a c source file "tcp.c", and it has two local functions( 84 and 64 are the size of each function).

I think that in ELF files, functions or variables of LOCAL type always have the FILE name in front of them.

However, global functions and variables are placed in the last part of the EFL file, and there are no FILE names in front of them.

How to get source file name of global OBJECT/FUNC in an elf file?

Comment: Why do you think that "_functions or variables of LOCAL type always have the FILE name in front of them_"? Doesn't this depends on the compiler and its mangling rules? In my C programs I don't see this.

Comment: @thebusybee  I'm not sure about that, but that's what I see in my ELF file.
I also searched some information. From the description here, I also think that local symbols is after its file symbol:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1386/6m7qcoblj/index.html#chapter6-35166

"Conventionally, the symbol's name gives the name of the source file associated with the object file. A file symbol has STB_LOCAL binding and its section index is SHN_ABS. This symbol, if present, precedes the other STB_LOCAL symbols for the file. ......."

Comment: Well, you might want to provide a [mre], together with information on the used compiler and how you obtain the information.

Comment: @thebusybee  I am using esp32. Based on the official project, the ELF file compiled by any demo is the same as what I said:    https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question. You don't mean a prefix like "tcp_..." for the names, you mean the sequence in the symbol table. Would you mind to add this for clarification in your question, please? -- Anyway, what do you want to accomplish? What sort of files are you looking at, object files or linked executables with debugging information?